# Will airdropping FCPX to another computer work?

Tags: mojave, final-cut-pro

Will Final Cut Pro X work if I airdrop it from one mac to another, and the macs use two different Apple IDs (through just airdropping the .app file, not other files). If only airdropping the .app is not enough, what other files do I need to airdrop?

Comment: The question you seem to be asking is "How can I give FCP to someone else." Apple has, needless to say, worked hard to make this more difficult than just copying the files.

Comment: @benwiggy so let’s put that in as an answer. No, just copying licensed software doesn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

No, copying software licensed to one AppleID does not work on another computer without that AppleID.

Your purchase is subject to Apple's terms and conditions, which may vary by region.